# LESS: Unrecognised input w/ strange characters

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, less, utf, web-essentials

[image]

Something is corrupting my .LESS files. They look fine in a text editor (VS2013 or Sublime) but when I try and compile them they have extra strange characters in them.

I get the same error if I try to compile using grunt or web essentials.

Why is this what the LESS compiler is reading?

```
��/ /   C o r e   v a r i a b l e s   a n d   m i x i n s
```

What is happening here? I'm guessing it has something to do with file encoding??? See screen shot above.

Comment: What happens if you remove the line? It seems there is a strange character before the `//` and produces the error.

Comment: I still get the error even if I delete the line.

Comment: Most likely it's UTF-[BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Some where in the menu (sorry I don't have this version of VS) you'll find options to change file format: make it "UTF-8 without BOM".

Answer (score -1):

- Toggle show whitespace characters (Edit / Advanced / View White Space);
- Remove first two chars;
- Save file;